# Multiplication functions

Tags: matrix

We use multiplication. In a symbolic way, everything works fine. When we try to multiply functions (matrices) it fails. When  we create matrices with other functions, multiplication does not occur.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Comment: replace `a={{...}}//MatrixForm` with `(a={{...}})//MatrixForm` as `MatrixForm` is wrapper.

Comment: Works great !!! Thank you so much for your help!